# System randomly unresponsive, apps freezing, possibly related to videos in browser

Tags: freeze, crash, youtube

I've been using Ubuntu 18 for about half a year now and up until a few weeks ago I didn't have any issues. However, my system became annoyingly unstable at seemingly random times: music playing in YouTube stutters or stops, the whole system is completely unresponsive (hardly any clicks work, more often than not I can't even close programs), progams crash or freeze, often times the internet stops working (probably due to the WiFi disconnecting for some reason), sometimes my external mouse stops working and I have to use the touch pad (and sometimes even that stops working). It then takes the system a few seconds to minutes to become responsive again. I checked the system monitor during such a system freeze (which also crashes most of the time) and could not see an increase in CPU or RAM usage.

I think that it might have something to do with YouTube (which usually always plays music when I'm working) because the system seems to be more stable when no website playing a video is open. Also, it seems that it is more stable when I have YouTube running in an extra window which I minimize (as opposed to just switch to another window leaving the browser running YouTube maximized in the background). This happens with Chrome *and* Firefox. When I googled this I found that disbaling hardware acceleration and GPU rasterization might help. I did this but it did not help.

Things that might or might not have something to do with this:

- I have a parallel installation of Windows 10.
- About three weeks ago Ubuntu wouldn't start, displaying "Volume
  corrupt" and startup. I was able to fix this with a boot repair
  stick. I am not 100% sure but I think that the system was
  unstable before that.
- I'm using Gnome Tweak.
- Every single time I boot the system I get an error with no further
  details and I get the option to "send a report" or cancel. No idea
  what that is about, but it only recently started. I tried to get rid
  of this by some terminal command I found when I googled this issue,
  didn't work though.

My system info:

- Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS 64 bit
- Intel i5-8265U
- No dedicated graphics
- 24 GB memory

Any suggestions to fix this would be much appreciated. Since I am fairly new to Linux, I don't know if there is anything else I could provide you with that would be helpful in order to investigate this. I'm glad to do so though, if you just let me know :)

Thanks!

Edit: I do not think that it has something to do with video per se anymore. I just pushed a rather large commit into a remote repo which took around 10 minutes without any browser being open. Every ~15 seconds or so the whole system became unresponsive, my mouse and the internet stopped working. It took another 10-20 seconds before it responded again and continued to upload.

[screenshot of the system monitor while pushing. the monitor was unresponsive as well while everything else went down.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkByf.png)

Answer (score 1):

In kernal versions 5+ there is a bug where browsers render the gpu and write to the disk at the same time. This happens on random machines not all of them.

The current fix is to install and set up **"profile-sync-daemon"** you may also need to enable **Overlayfs**. Profile sync daemon writes your browser cache to ram and thus mitigating the artificial IO bottle neck.

This affects AMD and Intel

They talk about it on Linux Unplugged EP.352 at the very end.